# Importing a php.inc file into a PERL program

Tags: php, linux, perl

I'm trying to use 1 include file for both perl and php

Is there a nice way to import a myphp.inc file within perl?

```
$ cat myphp.inc
<?php
    $some_var="hello world";
?>
```

Using the above in my test.php works fine:

```
include "myphp.inc";
```

If I remove the  < ? php then test.php will just print out the contents of the myphp.inc file... if I leave them in then my perl programs complains with:

```
Unterminated <> operator
```

I've seen the perl module: PHP::Include but I would like to stay away from external modules if possible.

Anyone have ideas on doing this??

Answer (score 9):

Don't try to write code that is both PHP and Perl, they are different languages, even if they have some shared ancestry. If you want to share data between the two, then use a structured data format. [JSON](http://json.org/) is a popular flavour. PHP has [parse_json](http://php.net/parse_json) and Perl has the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) module.

> I would like to stay away from external modules if possible

Code reuse is a virtue … although there is nothing stopping you reimplementing the modules from scratch.

Comment: I'm really just trying to set some global variables for both so I don't have to edit my perl.inc and php.inc files.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure I buy this... so when I have some global'ish vars like $MAX_ROWS and $CUSTOMER_SOMETHING (up to 30 vars total) that both my php and perl progs use, I should be encoding these in some other format and reading them in (ie JSON?) ... that seems like overkill

Comment: @Douglas, think of $MAX_ROWS and friends as runtime configuration parameters.  Store them in a format that makes sense for your programs and for your platform — a configuration file (JSON?), the registry, a wrapper script that sets environment variables, a web service, whatever.

Comment: Even a `.ini` like file that just has `key: value` or `key=value` lines makes more sense than this. It doesn't have to be JSON, it's just handy because it's simple to parse. It's easier to make those configuration parameters editable by a user that way, too.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would store the shared/configuration data in a format easily readable in both PHP and Perl. XML, JSON, or a simple text file with key-value pairs (as in the .ini file that simbabque suggests) would work great.

If you are determined to read the PHP file in Perl but you do not want to use a module such as PHP::Include then you are left with writing something like this:

```
use IO::File;

sub require_php {
        my $source_filename = $_[0];
        my $dest_filename = 'temp.inc.pl';
        open my $source, $source_filename or die "Could not open $source_filename: $!";
        open my $destination, '>>'.$dest_filename or die "Cound not open file for writing";
        while(my $line = <$source>) {
                if(index($line,'<?php')==-1 && index($line,'?>')==-1) {
                        print $destination $line
                }
        }
        close $destination;
        close $source;
        require $dest_filename;
        unlink $dest_filename;
}

our $some_var = '';
require_php('myphp.inc');
```

which will end with `$some_var` having the value of "hello world".